# How to use Promise.All in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I use promise.All to wait finish methods before render component.*

**I used like this :**

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.controllAll();
      }

    controllAll() {
    Promise.all([this.callFetch()])
      .then(([fetchResponse]) => {
          console.log('finished', fetchResponse);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Mistake:', err);
      });
    }

    callFetch() {
fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
                      Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
            }),
       })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then(leaders => {

            this.PutImagesToObject(leaders );
        });

    }
```

*I want to wait to finish callfetch() method finish before render Component. But when I run, firstly in debug mode I see 'finished'.*

*Doesnt have to wait to finish CallFetch() method to show me 'finished'*

Comment: `callFetch` doesn't return a promise so there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: What should I add ?

Comment: A `return`. Also, there is no reason to use `Promise.all`, just call `then.

Comment: Can u add code because I dont know how to use promise just  I saw on web and used

Answer (score 0):

Try to add return statement

```
callFetch() {
  return fetch('url', {
  ...
```